# Meteor : I am working on Reset password functionality, Getting "Token Undefined" while passing from client to server

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, angular-meteor

User gets an Tokenised URL to his EMAIL reset password.
URL is sent from Server side.
Now when User hits URL, he is navigated to Reset password screes at CLIENT side.

When user enter password , and click Reset button. I am Calling "Reset password" method present at  server side using meter.call().
I want to pass Token and new password to that function as input.
how can i get that token which was generated at Server side to Client side.

Present i am getting this error : Token Undefined

Comment: Instead of a `Meteor.call`, you can use `Accounts.resetPassword` on the client side.

Comment: aedm : i am using this meteor.call('Accounts.resetPassword', token,pass) ;
As my Accounts.resetPassword method is at server side. I got to know that server side methods are called using meteor.call()

Comment: Try `Accounts.resetPassword(token, pass);` without `Meteor.call`. See: http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-resetPassword

Comment: I wil be able to call server side function fromClient using this?

Comment: You don't need to call a server-side function here, `Accounts.resetPassword` does it for you.

Comment: Can we discuss this in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a tokenised URL, you could figure out some way to parse the URL to retrieve the token. Getting the current URL is just:

```
document.URL
```

This could be even easier if you used Iron Router, as you could use `this.params` to find the token you stored inside the URL.

Comment: Yes got that , Now i am facing "Malformed method invocation" on calling server side function. Any leads for solution???

Comment: What does your "server side function" look like and how are you calling it? I'm guessing that error means you're passing in incorrect arguments.